# After tapping programmatically the row doesnt got highlighted in listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view which i have populated and after populating it i have made a click programmatically which make my listview onItemclick event to be executed. Till here its fine but my problem is i cant able to highlight the row which is programmatically clicked i have set the background color to be changed on click event here i am putting my code

```
messageListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                try {
//                  arg1.setSelected(true);
                    lastSelectedView1.setBackgroundColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    lastSelectedView2.setBackgroundColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    lastSelectedTextView1.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastSelectedTextView2.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastSelectedTextView3.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastSelectedView.setBackgroundColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    lastFriendNameTextView.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastSentMessageLabelTextView.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastSentMessageTextView.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastReceivedMessageLabelTextView
                            .setTextColor(HomeActivity.this.getResources()
                                    .getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastReceivedMessageTextView.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastPhoneNumberTextView.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this
                            .getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(">>>Exception>>>" + e.toString()
                            + ">>>Message>>>" + e.getMessage());
                }

                try {
                    View view1 = arg1.findViewById(R.id.top_layout);
                    View view2 = arg1.findViewById(R.id.row_background);
                    TextView textView1 = (TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    textView1.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this.getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.white));
                    TextView textView2 = (TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    textView2.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this.getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.white));
                    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.time_textview);
                    timeTextView.setTextColor(HomeActivity.this.getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.white));
                    view1.setBackgroundColor(HomeActivity.this.getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    view2.setBackgroundColor(HomeActivity.this.getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
                    lastSelectedView1 = view1;
                    lastSelectedView2 = view2;
                    lastSelectedTextView1 = textView1;
                    lastSelectedTextView2 = textView2;
                    lastSelectedTextView3 = timeTextView;
                    isSelectedFromMessageList = true;
                    selectedItemFromMessageList = messageArrayList.get(arg2).Name;
                    selectedContactItem = arg2;
                    // createMessageLayout(selectedItemFromMessageList);

                    // setListButtonBackground();
                    createMessageLayout(messageArrayList.get(arg2).Name);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(">>>Exception>>>" + e.toString()
                            + ">>>Message>>>" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Whats wrong with my code???

Comment: have you know about list selector ?

Comment: Better use CustomAdapter which extends BaseAdapter class and override the getView method.

Comment: Anirudha can u show me a sample code by an example.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a background.xml under drawable folder

```
background.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/cyan" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

And set the android:background = "@drawable/background"  for your list row

Comment: I have several items in my item layout i want to make background color dark and text color white

Comment: After click , are u changing text and background color or only background color

Comment: I am changing both text color and background color

Comment: then you need to use custom adapter and override it get View methos,Also add on itemClickListener in getView to change text and background color